# What is the "X-iinfo" HTTP header?

Tags: http, http-headers, response-headers

I've seen an HTTP header called `X-iinfo`. Her are some examples:

```
X-Iinfo: 5-17009424-17011001 PNNN RT(1388193526625 4677) q(0 0 0 -1) r(1 1) U10000

X-Iinfo:4-13055499-13055501 NNNN CT(182 -1 0) RT(1388193578304 0) q(0 0 1 4) r(6 6) U1
```

Parts of them (but not all) seem to change on refresh.

What is this header?

Comment: A little context would be helpful. What is giving this? HTTP headers are not limited to standard ones, so a website can generate any header it wants with any data in it.

Comment: yes. probably the website you are visiting, could have stuffed them to better communicate with its own server subsequently.

Comment: I've seen it on a number of websites. I'll do some research on my own.

Answer (score 11):

I can confirm that it is a incapsula CDN header and i talked with then about a cache and got this info about it:

```
X-Iinfo:9-49176764-0 0CNN RT(1426425483129 667) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1)
```

The **C** letter in the 0**C**NN above indicates the the resource is served from cache.

```
X-Iinfo:4-152072-152074 PVNN RT(1415979066955 4498) q(0 0 0 -1) r(2 2)
```

The **V** letter in the P**V**NN indicates the same, plus, that the resource passed validation (in the backend servers) and it is fresh.

```
X-Iinfo:4-152072-152074 PNNN RT(1415979066955 4498) q(0 0 0 -1) r(2 2)
```

Any other letter on that field will indicate that the resource is not served from cache and was fetch directly from the backend

Comment: In the latest releases I think this has changed a bit, **0CNN** is still cached, but now I see **SNNN** and **NNNN**.

Comment: @Baris right, so you got a *N* in the 2 position on both those examples, that means that the resource was fetch from the backend. Notice the last sentence of my post. :)

Comment: no docs nor links, as a client i created a ticket to incapsula asking for more information about the headers and got the above info. the other fields are for their internal use and they didn't gave more info.

Answer (score 10):

After I pointed out to Imperva that their WAF Cloud Security customers are relying on Stack Overflow to interpret their header they have now kindly now included it in their documentation:

https://docs.imperva.com/bundle/cloud-application-security/page/settings/caching.htm

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be related to the [Incapsula](http://www.incapsula.com/) search engine. Every site I found that supplied the `X-Iinfo` header also supplied `X-CDN: Incapsula`.

I couldn't find documentation on what the numbers mean, but the first number after `RT` appears to be a date. The rest would require more investigation.